# make: Nothing to be done for 'serialobjs'

Tags: python, c++, gcc, makefile, lib

I am trying to install one code while doing make command I am facing such type of issue

```
poonam@poonam:~/Downloads/wannier90-3.1.0$ make

(cd ./src/obj && make -f ../Makefile.2 serialobjs)

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/poonam/Downloads/wannier90-3.1.0/src/obj'

make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'serialobjs'.

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/poonam/Downloads/wannier90-3.1.0/src/obj'

(cd ./src/obj && make -f ../Makefile.2 wannier)

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/poonam/Downloads/wannier90-3.1.0/src/obj'

mpifort ../wannier_prog.F90 -DMPI -O2 constants.o io.o utility.o parameters.o hamiltonian.o 

overlap.o kmesh.o disentangle.o ws_distance.o wannierise.o plot.o transport.o sitesym.o comms.o

 -L/usr/local/lib  -llapack -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -o ../../wannier90.x

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf77blas

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

../Makefile.2:42: recipe for target '../../wannier90.x' failed

make[1]: *** [../../wannier90.x] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/poonam/Downloads/wannier90-3.1.0/src/obj'

Makefile:37: recipe for target 'wannier' failed

make: *** [wannier] Error 2
```

can anyone please suggest me why this is happening and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your program appears to be in Fortran so you tag Python and C++?

Comment: You seem to be missing a bunch of required libs: `f77blas` `cblas` `atlas`. Install these first. Is there a `configure` to run first? It should check all the dependencies so when you run make it is ready to go.

Comment: With regard to the title question, why do you think there should be anything to do for target serialobjs?  And what makes you think we can tell you any more than you already know when you do not present the makefiles involved?